# python regex match anything between string multiple conditions

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to get my hands dirty on regex.

Sample String

```
Info:Somestring-103409115825.Call
Info: BIL*ONL*00003.Avbl
```

Currently This Matches

```
>>> print(re.search(r'Info:(.*?).Call', payload).group(1))
Somestring-103409115825

>>> print(re.search(r'Info:(.*?).Avbl', payload).group(1))
BIL*ONL*00003
```

how to make regex to match both conudtion like `Info -- AnyString -- .Call|.Avbl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the dot and place it before using an alternation to match either Call or Avbl

```
\bInfo:(.*?)\.(?:Call|Avbl)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hAJAmC/1)

```
import re
 
pattern = r"\bInfo:(.*?)\.(?:Call|Avbl)\b"
 
print(re.search(pattern, "Info:Somestring-103409115825.Call").group(1))
print(re.search(pattern, "Info: BIL*ONL*00003.Avbl").group(1))
```

**Output**

```
Somestring-103409115825
 BIL*ONL*00003
```

If you don't want the leading space before the group value, you can use:

```
\bInfo:\s*(.*?)\.(?:Call|Avbl)\b
```

[See a Python demo](https://ideone.com/EatVHg)

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.

```
import re

payload1 = 'Info:Somestring-103409115825.Call'
payload2 = 'Info: BIL*ONL*00003.Avbl'

print(re.search(r'Info:(.*?)((.Call)|(.Avbl))', payload1).group(1))
print(re.search(r'Info:(.*?)((.Call)|(.Avbl))', payload2).group(1))
```